# When hovering over image how to show description overlaying adjacent image?

Tags: jquery, css, hover

Hope someone can help me or point me in the right direction.

I want to display a grid of images, where the user can hover over an image to get more info, just as it's been done [here](http://www.tiffany.co.uk/Shopping/CategoryBrowse.aspx?mcat=148204&cid=287464&search_params=s+5-p+1-c+287464-r+201323339-x+-n+12-ri+-ni+1-t+).

Is this an easy thing to do? Can I do it with pure CSS or would I need to use jQuery?  I just need a pointer in the right direction if possible please?

Comment: If you want to rip off someone else's design, just View Source.

Comment: You'll have to use jQuery for something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link you gave seems to first give an hover state of the background image and then via a timeOut it displays a tooltip. I am working on a fiddle to make this clear.

---

So, here you go. Here is the [Fiddle](http://bramvanroy.be/infoToolTip/)!

The most important thing is the jQuery which contains a delay AND also the hover state of the image stated in the CSS. So when a user hovers the image the first thing he gets is another image. This is done by simple CSS hover and **CSS sprites**.

```
.item {
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top; 
}

.item:hover {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center bottom; 
}

#flower {
    background-image: url('http://bramvanroy.be/files/images/tooltipOverlay.jpg');
}
```

When the image is hovered at the beginning, a jQuery function is triggered BUT it is delayed:

```
var tooltip = $(".item-tooltip");

tooltip.hide();

$(".item-wrapper").hover(
function() {
    $(this).children(tooltip).delay(550).fadeIn("slow");
    $(this).children(".item").fadeOut("slow");
},
...
​
```

And when the mouse leaves the tooltip, it gets hidden and the `.item` is shown again:

```
...  
    function(){
        $(this).children(tooltip).fadeOut("fast");
        $(this).children(".item").fadeIn("fast");
    }
);
```

- More on jQuery's [.delay()](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/y5nYN/17/)
- More on [CSS sprites](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/y5nYN/18/)
- [Image copyright](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/hoverIntent)

---

**IMPROVED ANSWER:**

Here is a [Showcase](http://bramvanroy.be/infoToolTip/), here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/y5nYN/17/) of that showcase and here is the fiddle in which the image [does not change](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/y5nYN/18/) (as you wanted).

I have used the jQuery plugin [hoverIntent](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/hoverIntent) to make sure that not every image that gets hovered even for a milisecond shows a tooltip. What it does is checking whether it is the user's **intention** to hover the image and only then (after a certain timeOut) executing the function. More info on this plug in over [here](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html). You can use the standard hover() of jQuery, but I won't advise it.

The z-index needed to be changed as well, otherwise the image would appear beneath the tooltip **OR** the image of the other item would overlap the tooltip of the image that we want.

If you have any more question, please do say so in the comments.

Comment: Hi Bram, thank you for the code.  I should have been clearer about what I actually need... sorry.  I don't need a second image to show, so won't need the delay, but only the description to show when the user hovers over the tooltip.  This may be a better example

Comment: Oops... hit enter too early.  This may be a better example:  http://www.pullandbear.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/category/pullandbeargb/en/pullandbear/244504/CUTE%2BPRICES.  The only difference being that all images will be the same size, and I want to have clickable links in the tooltip. If you have any additional tips that will help that would be great,but otherwise I think you've given me enough for me to try and work it out... Thanks again :-)

Comment: I'll work something out earlier today. So you do NOT need the image to change on hover? Only additional information?

Comment: Yes please ... I just want the the info to be displayed over the adjacent image when the user hovers over the image they want info for.  I would really appreciate the help ... Thank you so so much :)

Comment: I have added the solution that I think you want. It's under the heading **IMPROVED ANSWER** .

Comment: You are an absolute genious.  That worked perfectly. I really did not expect to receive the level of help you have given to me.  I really appreciate it thank you.  I just have one question. In your example when you hover over the last item in the row, the tooltip displays on the left, but when I have done it, proportion of the tooltip is shown up until the right edge of the wrapper. Do you have a solution I can use to fix this?  Thanks again... I'm a very happy lady right now ;)

Comment: I am sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean. Can give a screenshot/showcase/fiddle of what you mean? And you are welcome. Always glad to help.

Comment: I edited the fiddles because I felt like they needed improving. I've edited a timeOut to the change of z-index to improve the smoothness of the transition.

Comment: Hi Bram, I'll send you a link to my site, so you can see what I mean

Comment: How will you send me this? As far as I know, sO doesn't have private messages?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10390/discussion-between-amara-and-bram-vanroy)

Answer (score 1):

What i would do is use jquery.  Create a div that is visible and then one that is hidden that displays the information you want to when you hover.  Then simply use jquery to hide/show that div using css.

```
$(".info-class").hover(function(){
    $(this).css('display', 'none');
    $(".other-clas").css('display', 'block');
});
```

Something similar to above

Comment: Thanks Chad, this looks like a very simple method. I'll give it a try and see how I get on with it.  Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I have looked at what they are doing on that website and it looks over engineered to me.

What I would do is us add

```
<div class="comtainer">
    <div id="g11" class="square large" data-show-tooltip-in="#g12, #g12">
        <div class="normal-view"><img ... ></div>
        <div class="large-view"><img ... ></div>
        <div class="tooltip">blah blah</div>
    </div>
    <div id="g12" class="square small" data-show-tooltip-in="#g13">
       ...
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

css

```
div.large-view { display : none; }
div.tooltip    { display : none; }
```

and then the javascript would do something like (JQuery for speed):

```
$( '.square' ).on( 'mouseover', function*(e){
     //hides the normal image
     $( this ).find( '.normal-view' ).hide();
     //shows the zoomed image
     $( this ).find( '.large-view' ).show();
     //stores a reference to the square where the HTML tolltip will be shown
     var $tooltip = $( $( this ).attr( 'data-show-tooltip-in' ) );
     //hides the original content of the tooltip square
     $tooltip.find( 'div' ).hide();
     //clones the tooltip to the other square and shows it
     $( this ).find( '.tooltip' ).clone().qppendTo( $tooltip ).show();
})
```

This is just a starting point, but that's how I would go about it.

**EDIT** added explanation

In the HTML there is series of div of class square (they could also be li's in a ul list, but that's unimportant now). Each square has all the data it needs - the normal image, the zoomed image, and the tooltip HTML. The last two are hidden in CSS. Each square has also a data- attribute (data-show-tooltip-in) with the selector(s) where the tooltip will be displayed.

Then the JS makes does the rest - the comments should help.

Comment: Thank you I'll give it a shot and let you know how I get on. Not sure I understand what is going on here thought to be honest.  The way I want to do it all the images will be of equal size

Comment: Added some comments. Hope that helps.

Comment: I get it thanks. I think I was too tired when I got home last night after going to a party ;-).  My apologies for not being clear about what I need exactly, I don't actually need the second example. This example is a much better one http://www.pullandbear.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/category/pullandbeargb/en/pullandbear/244504, with out the fancy scrolling, although I do like it ;-). I didn't realise you can apply custom attributes to elements.  That's good to know. I'm going to see if I can get this to work.... Thank you